# make if statement based on current URL (without specifying)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm basically trying to display specific RSS feeds based on the current URL. I have got somewhat there with the below solution, but I would not like to specify URLs in a variable, but rather check the current URL and `if it contains` then do / pull my rss feed.
The below solution can't work because I need to do multiple checks on multiple URLs.

```
jQuery(function($) { //  display rss feed based on current URL

// start conditions to display 3 feeds on different URLs

  var url = 'http://localhost:8888/';

  if (url.indexOf('8888') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }
  if (url.indexOf('movies') > -1) { 
      $(".feed1").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed2").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
      $(".feed3").rss("http://www.thehollywoodgossip.com/rss.xml",
      {
        limit: 17,
        entryTemplate:'<h1 class="feedtitle"><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a></h1><br/><div class="featimg">{teaserImage}</div><div class="feedtxt">{shortBodyPlain}</div>'
      })
  }

.......
```

*Note that the feed URLs will be different. this is just a sample.*

Comment: Is this question about how to check current URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8888/';
```

do

```
var url = window.location.href;
```